# What causes maven-javadoc-plugin goal test-javadoc to fail on errors but test-javadoc-no-fork just to have warnings

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I have a Maven project with maven-javadoc-plugin and JDK8. When I run `mvn javadoc:test-javadoc` then the plugin reports documentation-errors and stops, but when I run `mvn javadoc:test-javadoc-no-fork` the plugin runs successful and there's just some warnings.

The question is **NOT** how to fix or the documentation-errors. The plugin spotted real documentation-issues, that need to be fixed, so the reported errors of `mvn javadoc:test-javadoc` are the correct result.

The question is: **Why does `mvn javadoc:test-javadoc-no-fork` not fail but handle the issues just as warning?**

---

Background:

- the project is a multi-module-project
- Maven version: 3.3.9
- maven-javadoc-plugin: 2.9.4 (the same behaviour occurs for 3.0.0-M1)
- Java8

---

The sported problem in `TracingServiceSpringTest` has really a missing documentation for the thrown `DatatypeConfigurationException`

```
/** scenario: some text... **/
@Test
public void testImport() throws DatatypeConfigurationException {...
```

---

Output when running `mvn javadoc:test-javadoc`

```
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.4:test-javadoc (default-cli) < generate-test-sources @ agrovet-server <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.4:test-javadoc (default-cli) @ agrovet-server ---
[INFO]
...
3 errors
9 warnings
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] PROJECT ............................................ SUCCESS [  1.131 s]
[INFO] PROJECT :: Client .................................. SUCCESS [ 43.908 s]
[INFO] PROJECT :: Server .................................. FAILURE [ 44.774 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:36 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-23T21:33:33+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 96M/1573M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.4:test-javadoc (default-cli) on project PROJECT-server: An error has occurred in Test JavaDocs report generation:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - F:\workspaces\PROJECT\PROJECT-server\src\test\java\com\example\PROJECT\infrastructure\TracingServiceSpringTest.java:389: warning:
no @throws for javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException
[ERROR] public void testImport() throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
[ERROR] ^
...
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @packages
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Refer to the generated Javadoc files in 'F:\workspaces\PROJECT\PROJECT-server\target\site\testapidocs' dir.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

...
```

---

Output when running `mvn javadoc:test-javadoc-no-fork`

```
8 warnings
[WARNING] Javadoc Warnings
[WARNING] F:\workspaces\PROJECT\PROJECT-server\src\test\java\com\example\PROJECT\infrastructure\TracingServiceSpringTest:389: warning: no @throws for javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException
[WARNING] public void testImport() throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
[WARNING] ^
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] PROJECT ............................................ SUCCESS [  0.454 s]
[INFO] PROJECT :: Client .................................. SUCCESS [  0.011 s]
[INFO] PROJECT :: Server .................................. SUCCESS [  6.763 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

---

Relevant POM Parts, parent `pom.xml` (the complete pom is just too huge, but this is the only part that mentions the `maven-javadoc-plugin` :

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
        </plugin>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
...
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <!-- 
                        javadoc-no-fork in order to prevent JavaDoc process from runing generate-source again
                        but this also requries that JavaDoc generation runs after compile: "mvn install site"
                        but not on a black project "mvn clean site"
                        -->
                        <report>javadoc-no-fork</report>
                        <report>test-javadoc-no-fork</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Answer (score 1):

While trying to [Generate Javadoc without duplicate execution of phase generate-sources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/javadoc-nofork.html). As of version 2.10 two new reports are defined, `javadoc-no-fork` and `test-javadoc-no-fork` will not trigger `generate-sources` or `generate-test-sources` phases again a second time.

When you use the option [`test-javadoc-no-fork`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/test-javadoc-no-fork-mojo.html)  the test-source generation is skipped and hence your build succeeds.

> ...generates the test Javadoc files for the
>   project. It executes the standard Javadoc tool and supports the
>   parameters used by the tool without forking the generate-test-sources
>   phase again. Note that this goal does require generation of test
>   sources before site generation, e.g. by invoking `mvn clean deploy site`.

on the other hand [`javadoc:test-javadoc`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/test-javadoc-mojo.html) the test-sources are compiled again and the error is logged.

> generates the test Javadoc files for the project. It executes the
>   standard Javadoc tool and supports the parameters used by the tool.

---

All of that with the `<reportSets>`

> Multiple specifications of a set of reports, each having (possibly)
>   different configuration. This is the reporting parallel to an
>   `<execution>` in the build.

both of type `no-fork`, you can try and include `test-javadoc` as one of the reports in the `<reportSet>` to solve this.

Comment: But this issues are no compiler issues. The issues are just that the javadoc for an thrown exception is missing. -- And the javadoc tool is even when running `test-javadoc-no-fork` recognizing that problem (it generate a warning) but it does not stop the build.

Comment: @Ralph Ya probably I got you wrong initially. Trying to reproduce the same with one class each in my test and main, I was unable to get the failure for both the commands though. Also you can try and include `test-javadoc` as one of the reports and see if that helps.